# "/app/config/parameters.ini file is not valid" when trying to deploy

Tags: symfony

I'm getting the following error when I try to deploy my Symfony2 app with Capifony:

> The
>   "/path/cap/myapp/releases/20121227024938/app/config/parameters.ini"
>   file is not valid.

This is what parameters.ini looks like for me:

```
; These parameters can be imported into other config files
; by enclosing the key with % (like %database_user%)
; Comments start with ';', as in php.ini
[parameters]
    database_driver   = pdo_mysql
    database_host     = localhost
    database_name     = symfony
    database_user     = root
    mailer_transport  = smtp
    mailer_host       = localhost
    locale            = en
    secret            = ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

I could deploy fine until recently. The parameters.ini file is just copied from the example. What could be the deal?

Comment: Have you upgraded from symfony2.0 to symfony2.1 or similar?

Comment: If it used to work but no longer does, and the format of the parameters.ini file is fine, I would double check file permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Symfony 2.1 uses `parameters.yml` and not `parameters.ini`, I decided to just blow away `parameters.ini` and any reference to it. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the "secret" token.  Change "ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt" to a secret pass phrase or string.

Comment: Hmm, that seems not to have had any effect.

Comment: Doesn't seem that it would matter but have you aleo verified that your database settings & credentials are correct?  Are you missing any required values?  Do you have any more information on why it thinks the file is invalid?